# Django Many To Many Complaining about PrimaryKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have three models that are related. The first is called DayOfWeek, which is juts a day label and number. It looks like this:

```
class DayOfWeek(models.Model):
  day = models.IntegerField()
  label = models.CharField(max_length='20')

  def __str__(self):
    return self.label
```

This class is populated using a fixture every time I syncdb.Next, I have an event model, it looks like this:

```
class Event(AnnouncementBase, Location):
  cost = CurrencyField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=True, default=0.00)
  start_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.now().date())
  start_time = models.TimeField(default = datetime.now().time())
  end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=None, null = True)
  end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, default=None, null = True)
```

Finally, there is a recurrence. It has an event and is used to schedule the event for recurring events. It looks like this:

```
class Recurrence(models.Model):

  event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='event')
  repeats  = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = EVENT_REPEAT_CHOICES)
  repeat_every = models.IntegerField(default = 1)

  repeat_on = models.ManyToManyField(DayOfWeek, blank=True, null=True)

  repeat_by = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = EVENT_REPEAT_BY_CHOICES, blank=True)
  repeat_by_day_of_month = models.IntegerField(default = 0, blank=True)

  repeat_ends = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = EVENT_REPEAT_END_CHOICES)
  end_occurrences = models.IntegerField(default = 0, blank=True)
  repeat_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=None, null = True)

  past_event_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
  scheduled_events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, default=None, related_name = 'scheduled_events')
  is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)

   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
      """Overridden to create events the first time."""

      self.full_clean()
      #First do  normal save so the data is there for the even scheduler.
      self.save_base(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using)

      #If nothing is scheduled yet, schedule the first batch
      if self.scheduled_events.count() == 0 and self.past_event_count == 0:
          self.scheduleEvents()


  def clean(self):
      #repeat on weekly
      if self.repeat_every < 1:
          raise ValidationError('Repeat every must be at least 1.')


      #weekly
      if self.repeats == EVENT_REPEAT_CHOICES[1][0]:
        #look for missing stuff
        if not self.repeat_on:
            raise ValidationError('Missing repeat on.')
```

Finally, I have a unit test that checks this works ok it looks like this:

```
def test_weekly_mon_wed_fri_occurrence(self):
    event = Event()
    event.start_date = date(year=2012, month=1, day=2)
    event.start_time = time(hour=13, minute=30)
    event.save()

    recurrence = Recurrence()
    recurrence.repeats = EVENT_REPEAT_CHOICES[1][0]
    recurrence.repeat_on = (EVENT_DAY_CHOICES[1][0], EVENT_DAY_CHOICES[3][0], EVENT_DAY_CHOICES[5][0])
    recurrence.repeat_ends = EVENT_REPEAT_END_CHOICES[0][0]
    recurrence.event = event

    nextEvent = recurrence.getNextEvent(event)

    self.assertEquals(date(year=2012, month=1, day=4), nextEvent.start_date)
    self.assertEquals(event.start_time, nextEvent.start_time)

    nextNextEvent = recurrence.getNextEvent(nextEvent)

    self.assertEquals(date(year=2012, month=1, day=6), nextNextEvent.start_date)
    self.assertEquals(event.start_time, nextNextEvent.start_time)
```

Whenever the test is run it fails, with the following exception. 
    ValueError: 'Recurrence' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many   relationship can be used.

The error happens on the line if self.repeat_on in the clean method.

I want repeat_on to be optional, only some types of recurrences need it. How do I make this work? What am I missing that is causing it to fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `recurrence.save()` before assigning Many2Many relationships. In your code you do

```
recurrence.repeat_on = (EVENT_DAY_CHOICES[1][0], EVENT_DAY_CHOICES[3][0], EVENT_DAY_CHOICES[5][0])
```

without saving the recurrence first. Because its not saved, recurrence does not have primary key generated yet, and Django ORM doesn't know what to insert as a foreign key into the M2M table.

Comment: I'm not at home to try this yet, but I do have one question. Saving the recurrence calls clean, which caused the error. Also, even if it didn't cause this error it would cause clean to raise a validation error. There are some cases where a repeat_on value is required. How do I validate those without it breaking when repeat_on isn't required? The first call to save would always fail to validate wouldn't it?

Comment: You are correct, and this is a limitation of M2M relationships in Django. Notice that both model AND form have their own clean methods. Model's `clean` should be self-sufficient and validate only data resting on that model. You can either implement your own M2M table using `through` on Many2ManyField and add `clean` on the intermediery model and save foreign keys yourself, or what I think will fit you better, use Form's clean to validate the request as a whole first.